# How to force VC++ name mangling C++Builder?

Tags: c++, export, c++builder

Is it possible to export a function from a C++Builder DLL with a *specific* mangled name?
I am trying to build a C++Builder DLL to replace an existing `VC++` DLL. The problem is that the application that uses the DLL expects one of the functions to have a specific mangled name.

That is, it expects the function to be called:

```
"?_FUNCTIONNAME_@@YAHPAU_PARAM1_@@PAU_PARAM2_@@@Z"
```

Of course I can export function from my DLL with a mangled name but CodeGear insists on using its own name mangling scheme.

Is it possible to force C++Builder to:

1. Use a specific mangled name for a function?

   or
2. Use VC++ name mangling for a specific function?

Note that I only want to change the mangling for a specific function, not all the functions in the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Name mangling is just one of many aspects of the ABI.  And it fact it would be the more easy to standardize. Compilers are using purposefully different name manglings when they are using different ABI in order to prevent linking incompatible objects.

One thing you may try for a given function is to mark it `extern "C"`, then it will use the calling convention of C and the same mangling (commonly no mangling at all or just an initial `_`).  Obviously that won't take care of other issues (handling of exceptions, precise content of vtbls, which registers are used for passing parameters, the precise definition of the standard library, ...)

Comment: My understanding is that using `extern "C"` will stop the function name being mangled, where I actually want it to be mangled in a certain way.<br>I CodeGear allows developers to export functions with specific names, but I have only got this to work with simple export names, not complicated ones with mangling characters. I was wondering if anyone else had been able to get this to work.

Comment: +1, the mangling is there to protect you against incompatible ABI's. You should first figure out which VC++ ABI you're targetting anyway, IIRC the VC-pre-2005 ABI isn't compatible with the ABI from VC2005 and later.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `.def` file to specify your own naming for the exported function.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Unfortunately this only seems to work for simple names. When I tried doing this for a long, mangled, function name the linker threw an error. +1 for being the only person actually attempting to answer the question I asked, though.